# How to find out the wifi setting of a connected wifi network in MacBook Pro?

Tags: network, wifi

I have access to a MacBook Pro and a Android phone.

I know the username and password to a secured wifi network, but not the settings of the network e.g. PEAP or something else.

The Apple laptop is connected to the wifi network. The Android phone isn't, and it automatically detects the settings of network, and says the settings it detects are not correct when the connection fails.

So I want to find out the settings of the wifi network in MacBook Pro.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command in a Terminal (/Applications/Utilities):

```
system_profiler SPAirPortDataType
```

You can also see this information via the GUI app System Information.

System Information > Network > Wi-Fi

Just type System Information in Spotlight.